# How much water is in wet food?

Tags: diet

We have a couple questions about moisture benefits of wet food over dry food.  One example is [How often can I mix regular wet food with urinary health dry food?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7624) the top answer on that question identifies health benefits of feeding wet food.

On average how much more fluid/water is there in equal (by volume) amounts of wet versus dry pet food.

Comment: This is kinda a weird question because of the volume requirement. Wet foods tend to be 70-80% water by mass (IIRC), but measuring volume of kibble is weird.

Comment: Also, related http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1881/how-do-i-motivate-a-cat-to-drink-more-water/1886#1886

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but my vet pointed out that drinking is hard for cats, and in the wild they'd get a significant amount of their water intake from prey. She generally recommends wet food, or as much wet food as is practical, for that reason -- and that despite the possibility of increased dental disease.